# How many vertices does a planar graph need to have a complete $k$-colouring?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

A proper colouring $V(G) \to \{1,...,k\}$ of a graph $G$ is *complete* if every distinct pair of colours is connected by an edge. What is the least $n_k$ such that there exists a planar graph on $n_k$ vertices with a complete $k$-colouring?

Such a graph must have at least $\binom k2$ edges, and but because it is planar it can have no more than $3n-6$ edges, so immediately we get a naive bound $n_k\ge\bigl\lceil\tfrac{k(k-1)}6+2\bigr\rceil$ (for $k\ge3$). But this bound isn't always attainable:

> Suppose there exists a complete 6-colouring on a graph with $\bigl\lceil\tfrac{6\cdot5}6+2\bigr\rceil=7$ vertices. By the pidgeonhole principle, some pair of vertices must have the same colour, and upon their removal you'd have a complete 5-colouring of a 5-vertex graph—but this can only be the complete graph $K_5$, which is nonplanar. So $n_6>7$.

The first few values of $n_k$ are 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12. **Can $n_k$ be determined exactly for all $k$?** Failing that, are there better bounds than the quick and dirty ones below? $$\bigl\lceil\tfrac16k(k-1)+2\bigr\rceil\le n_k\le\bigl\lfloor\tfrac14k^2\bigr\rfloor \quad \text{(for $k\ge4$)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your question your may be rewritten as:

---

For each $k$, what is the smallest number $n$, such that there exists a planar graph $G$ having $n$ vertices and $\psi(G)=k$, where $\psi$ indicates the graph's *pseudochromatic* number.

---

As far as I know there does not exist an explicit formula for the sequence you asked about. However, some stronger bounds may be found [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/317557779_Complete_colorings_of_planar_graphs). For example, using your notation, in the article we may find that:
$$k \leq \Big\lfloor \sqrt{2n_k+\frac{1}{4}} +\frac{1}{2}\Big\rfloor$$

Comment: The formula you reference from that paper relates the pseudoachromatic number of any graph to its number of edges, but for me $n_k$ is the number of vertices and I care about the achromatic number. The bound in Thm 1(ii) looks more applicable, but you have to invert it first, to get an upper bound on $n_k$. If I'm not mistaken, it beats my naive upper bound when $k\ge22$.